Deep RL problem: Loss decreases but agent doesn't learn
I hope somebody can help me. I'm implementing a basic Vanilla Policy Gradient algorithm for the CartPole-v1 gymnasium environment, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
No matter what I try, during the training loop the loss decreases (so the model is actually learning something), but the episode total reward also decreases until it reaches around 9-10 steps (which I imagine is the minimum number of steps needed to make the pole fall). So it's learning to do it bad!
I don't know if it's something to do with the signs, the way I compute the loss, the optimizer... I have no idea.
For the discounted rewards I'm using
$ Q_{k,t} = \sum_{i=0}{\gamma^{i-t} r_i} $
And for the loss:
$ L = -\sum_{k,t}Q_{k,t}log\pi_{\theta}(a_t | s_t)$
The code is a mix from Maxim Lapan's Deep RL Hands-On book, Karpathy's Pong example (blog, code), and personal tweaks.
Here's my code:
import gymnasium as gym
import torch
from torch import nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.nn.init import xavier_uniform_
import numpy as np

GAMMA = 0.99
LEARNING_RATE = 0.001
BATCH_SIZE = 4
DEVICE = torch.device('mps')


class XavierLinear(nn.Linear):
    def __init__(self, in_features: int, out_features: int, bias: bool = True, device=None, dtype=None) -> None:
        super().__init__(in_features, out_features, bias, device, dtype)
        xavier_uniform_(self.weight)


class VPG(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, output_size):
        super(VPG, self).__init__()
        self.net = nn.Sequential(
            XavierLinear(input_size, 128),
            nn.ReLU(),
            XavierLinear(128, output_size), 
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return F.softmax(self.net(x), dim=0)


def run_episode(model, env):
    obs = env.reset()[0]
    obs = torch.Tensor(env.reset()[0]).to(DEVICE)
    te = tr = False
    rewards, outputs, actions = [], [], []
    while not (te or tr):
        probs = model(obs)
        action = probs.multinomial(1).item()
        obs, r, te, tr, _ = env.step(action)
        obs = torch.Tensor(obs).to(DEVICE)
        if (te or tr):
            r = 0
        rewards.append(r)
        outputs.append(probs)
        actions.append(action)
    return torch.Tensor(rewards).to(DEVICE), torch.concatenate(outputs).reshape(len(rewards), 2), actions

def discount_rewards(rewards):
    discounted_r = torch.zeros_like(rewards)
    additive_r = 0
    for idx in range(len(rewards)-1, -1, -1):
        to_add = GAMMA * additive_r
        additive_r = to_add + rewards[idx]
        discounted_r[idx] = additive_r
    return discounted_r.to(DEVICE)

def loss_function(discounted_r, probs, actions):
    logprobs = torch.log(probs)
    selected = logprobs[range(probs.shape[0]), actions]
    # discounted_r = (discounted_r - discounted_r.mean()) / discounted_r.std()
    weighted = selected * discounted_r
    return -weighted.sum()

# The actual training loop:

episode_total_reward = 0
batch_losses = torch.Tensor().to(DEVICE)
batch_actions = []
batch_disc_r = torch.Tensor().to(DEVICE)
batch_probs = torch.Tensor().to(DEVICE)
best_ep_reward = 0
losses, ep_total_lenghts = [], [0]

episodes = 0
TARGET_REWARD = 100

env = gym.make("CartPole-v1")
model = VPG(env.observation_space.shape[0],
            2).to(DEVICE)
optim = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=LEARNING_RATE)

while np.array(ep_total_lenghts)[-100:].mean() < TARGET_REWARD:
    rewards, probs, actions = run_episode(model, env)
    discounted_r = discount_rewards(rewards)
    episode_total_reward = rewards.shape[0]
    ep_total_lenghts.append(episode_total_reward)
    episodes += 1
    batch_actions += actions
    batch_disc_r = torch.concatenate([batch_disc_r, discounted_r])    
    batch_probs = torch.concatenate([batch_probs, probs])    

    if episodes % BATCH_SIZE == 0:
        loss = loss_function(batch_disc_r, batch_probs, batch_actions)
        losses.append(loss.item())
        model.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optim.step()
        batch_actions = []
        batch_disc_r = torch.Tensor().to(DEVICE)
        batch_probs = torch.Tensor().to(DEVICE)
        print(f"Episode {episodes}. Loss: {loss}. Reward: {episode_total_reward}")
print(f"Success in {episodes} episodes. Loss: {loss}. Reward: {episode_total_reward}")

Tried: changing signs in loss functions, changing rewards (non-terminal step = 0 and terminal step = -1), updating manually the weights (adding the gradient or substracting it...). In each case I get the same: the loss decreases but the agent doens't learn to keep the pole up.
Expectation: Loss decreases and episode total reward (steps played) increases.
EDIT:
I finally could fix the problem by applying these changes:

Inside run_episode, I change the reward for -1 if the episode is terminated and 0 otherwise:

r = -1 if te else 0


Uncommented this line inside loss_function:

discounted_r = (discounted_r - discounted_r.mean()) / discounted_r.std()


Also inside loss_function return the negative of the mean instead of the negative of the sum:

return - wieghted.mean()

With those changes I could fix the problem. Still I don't know why before it was decreasing the loss, but performing worse and worse. It was kinda learning backwards :).

It should be obvious after posting that Latex format does not render here.

Thanks for posting the solution. For the future, it is perfectly accepted to answer your own question and more logical than editing the question.

(Ah, or maybe you need 15 reputation for that though... huh.)

The only thing clearly jumping out to me right now is the VPG.forward.
You're doing a softmax over dim=0, but that would be the batch usually. You want to take the softmax over the action space to determine which action to take (probabilistically or if using eps-greedy strategy, etc). So instead, try changing to dim=-1 like this:
class VPG(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, output_size):
        super(VPG, self).__init__()
        self.net = nn.Sequential(
            XavierLinear(input_size, 128),
            nn.ReLU(),
            XavierLinear(128, output_size), 
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return F.softmax(self.net(x), dim=-1)  # softmax over action space

You're also resetting the environment twice which doesn't need to happen, but that shouldn't cause the effect you're seeing.

You're right. I had dim=0 because what's getting into the model has shape (4), it's unidimensional as I wasn't planning to use the model on a batch of states.
It works that way, but it's true that's better practice to use dim=-1.
The problem about learning was somewhere else, though, I'll edit the post to explain it
